# Determine the number of times a function will be called

Tags: counting

I have a function func[x], which is rather slow to evaluate.  It gets called (multiple times) inside other expressions; I'd like to know how many times it gets called (without actually evaluating the expression).  (This is so I can estimate how long it will take.)  For example, I'd like to make a function that would take     `3x*Hold[func[4]]+Hold[func[5]]*Hold[func[6]]` and return 3, because func would get called three times if I ran the code (with `ReleaseHold`).

I was thinking that string matching would be the way to go, namely come up with a list of symbols in `3x*Hold[func[4]]+Hold[func[5]]*Hold[func[6]]`, convert that into a list of strings, and then count the number of times `func` appears, but I haven't figured out a way to do the first two steps.

To be clear, I know that I'm always calling my function in expressions like the above, in which it's going to be evaluated once, so I only need to count the number of times "func" appears.

Help/ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at `Count`?

```
expr = HoldForm[3 x*func[4] + func[5]*func[6]]
Count[expr, func, ∞, Heads -> True]
```

> `3`

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I had tried count, but I was missing the "Heads->True", which makes it work.  Could you explain what that does?

Comment: @LaurenPearce. Rather than me write an explanation that would just quote the docs, I suggest you look at [this documentation article](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Heads.html) on the `Heads` option. Bear in mind that you are using `func` as a head in your expression.